# Oil for pan-frying lamb chop

Tags: frying, lamb

I'm learning to cook, and would like to pan-fry a lamb chop. I tried it yesterday, using a tempered chop and some EVOO in my medium-high heat stainless steel frying pan.

The result was kind-of OK -- just a bit rare for my liking. The oil smoked as soon as it hit the pan, and the room was very smoky by the end of it.

So, which oil would be best for pan-frying a lamb chop? Assuming I properly control the pan temperature this time!

Thanks

Comment: Related (essentially saying "don't use EVOO"): http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25469/why-does-my-olive-oil-smoke-burn-when-i-fry-with-it and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17605/can-extra-virgin-olive-oil-be-used-for-stir-frying-roasting-grilling ... there must be an actual duplicate around here somewhere.

Comment: I am against using the Rachael Rayism "EVOO" but I do disagree with the notion that you cannot sautee with extra virgin olive oil...

Comment: Also:  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/what-oil-to-use-when-cooking-steak-and-what-difference-does-it-make    Steaks are a very similar application to lamb chops.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Then you might want to look at http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27415/is-this-video-showing-an-exception-of-the-common-wisdom-that-you-shouldnt-cook and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-a-good-idea-or-a-waste-to-fry-with-olive-oil

Comment: Closing as dupe... we're starting to get separate question about which oil is best for every individual ingredient, and with extremely rare exceptions, it makes no difference at all *what* you're frying.

Answer (score 0):

Any food oil will do, except extremely strongly flavored oils like sesame oil.

You may use olive oil if its flavor will compliment the dish, and is to your taste.  You could even use animal fat like clarified butter, lard, or bacon fat if you choose, but each of these will bring a unique flavor.

You may choose a neutral oil if you want less flavor influence from the oil.

See also:
[What is meant by "neutral" oils?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19366/what-is-meant-by-neutral-oils)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Because of the low smoke point of EVOO, should I avoid it for pan frying?

Comment: That is a very contentious subject.  You will find research from olive oil consortiums indicating that it in fact has a high smoke point.  Obviously, refined olive oil will also be an option.  In sauteeing, though, you should not really be exceeding the smoke point of any reasonable oil, in my opinion.

Comment: Notably that same research rarely also deals with the question of whether there's actually any flavor left. The thing that plenty of people (like Harold McGee) keep saying is that sure, if it doesn't smoke, you can use it, but unless it's a very quick sautee, you'll lose all the good stuff anyway, and you might as well use something cheaper.

Comment: @Jefromi I find the olive oil from the consortiums incomplete and biased.  What I can say from my own experience is that sauteeing in olive oil is fine as long as it is done with reasonable care.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use extra virgin olive oil to cook with at higher temperatures. Ghee/clarified butter would be the best in terms of smoke point and flavour.

You can make your own also.

http://ilovetraditionalfoods.blogspot.ca/2013/03/how-to-make-ghee-at-home-clarified.html